# MySQL limiting indexes

Tags: mysql

I have a table: `tbl_table`

With colums: `col1`,`col2`,`col3`

I want to run a query such as `SELECT col1 FROM tbl_table WHERE col2=$variable AND col3=0`

To optimize this query I would need a multi-column index on `(col2,col3)` but since I will never run the query looking for `col3` as anything other than `0` it would be inefficient to index all `col3` possibilities. I would like to be able to create a multi-column index that only indexes whether `col3` is zero or not zero, not an index that indexes the entirety of `col3`.

This is for a real-world situation where I must do this. I have billions of records and the indexes are too large to fit on the drive, I need to trim them down.

Comment: You could use partitions over col3 in order to reduce the query search to a certain partition

Comment: Hi @RobertRozas, this table was previously partitioned and I'm moving away from that now due to bad results. Had to switch to TokuDB just to handle it, so no more partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

Running MySQL (or any rdms) in a scarce-storage environment is unreasonably difficult, especially when storage is cheap as it is in 2014.

MariaDB offers the concept of a Persistent Virtual Column.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/virtual-columns/. These can be indexed and loaded.  They do take storage.

You might try using one that's made from a function involving something like this:

```
Concat(if(col3=0,'z','n'),col2)
```

But if you're so storage-constrained you can't add an index, you probably won't be able to add a persistent virtual column with an index either.

If any of your tables are read only, you could try compressing them to free up storage.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/compressed-format.html